# Max of each tuple

Tags: python, python-3.5

How do I find the max for each tuple.

```
lst1 = [(4, 1, 9, 22, 6, 14),( 7, 22, 9, 2, 1, 2 )]
lst2 = map(max, zip(*lst1))
print(lst2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a list comprehension way is

```
lst2 = [max(x) for x in lst1]
```

Comment: Thank you Akavall, your answer is good too. However, I choose Hooting's due to the fact that I needed a list. I can always converted to tuple if i need to.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3:

```
In [1]: lst1 = [(4, 1, 9, 22, 6, 14),( 7, 22, 9, 2, 1, 2 )]

In [8]: tuple(map(max, lst1))
Out[8]: (22, 22)
```